# Plugin Galerías WordPress (lightgallery)

Tags: wordpress-plugin

estoy teniendo problemas con este plugin. 
Funciona correctamente pero en algunas ocasiones cuando accedo a un post no me muestra la imagen principal de la galería de imágenes.
Esto no ocurre siempre sólo algunas veces y para que muestre correctamente la imagen de la galería tengo que volver a recargar la página.
Un ejemplo de esto que comento se puede ver aquí:

https://sotoancho.com/instalacion/villa-equus/

¿Alguna idea de por qué puede ocurrir esto?

Muchas gracias,
Un saludo.
Isa.

Comment: Ese tipo de errores exigirían al que quisiera ayudarte el revisar un código de terceros que en ocasiones (de hecho normalmente) suele ser bastante extenso. Te recomiendo que te pongas en contacto con el soporte del plugin o que te remitas al FAQ para ver si es un problema ya tipificado. https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/lightgallery/

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow! Tu pregunta ha quedado un poco amplia y poco podemos ayudar a no ser que alguien haya tenido el mismo problema que tu. Mi recomendación es ir descartando cosas hasta que mas o menos encuentres el problema => plugin actualizado?, has actualizado wordpress y no es compatible? la foto no es soportada por ser demasiado grande? tiempos de carga insuficientes? . Siempre puedes buscar otros plugins. Aqui una pregunta al foro de ingles por si te ayuda [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319711/lightgallery-not-loading-images) Un saludo :)